# Where to begin for basic machine algorithms for, say, document recognition and organization?

Tags: machine-learning, web-applications, automation

Pardon if this question is not appropriate. It is kind of specific and I am not asking for actual code but moreso guidance on whether or not this task is worth undertaking. If this is not the place, please close the question and kindly point me in the correct direction.

**Short background:** I have always been interested in tinkering. I used to play with partitions and OS X scripts when I was younger, eventually reaching basic-level "general programming" aptitude before my father prohibited my computer usage. I am now going to law school and working at a law firm but I love development and I want to implement more tech innovation in the field.

**Main point:** At our firm, we have a busy season every year from mid march to the first week of april (immigration + H1B deadline). We receive a lot of documents and scanned files that need to be verified, organized, and checked.

I added (very) simple lines of code to our online platform to help in organization; basically, I attached tags to all incoming documents, and once they were verified, the code would organize them by tag (like "identification doc", "work experience doc" etc.). This would my life much easier every year, as I end up working 100+ hour weeks this season.

I want to take this many steps further with an algorithm that can check for signatures and data mismatches between documents and ultimately organize the documents so they are ready to print. Eventually, I would like to maybe even implement machine learning and a very basic neural network to automate the whole mind-numbing and painful process...

**Actual Question(s):** I just wanted to know the best way for me to proceed or get started. I know a decent amount of python and java, and  we have an online platform already with the documents. What other resources would you recommend in terms of books, videos, or even classes? Is there a name for this kind of basic categorization? Can I build something like this through my own effort without an advanced degree?

**Stupid and over-dramatic epilogue:** Truth be told, a part of me feels like I wasted my life thus far by not pursuing what I knew I loved at the age of 12. This is my way of making amends I guess, and if I can do this then maybe I can keep doing it in law and beyond...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give many specifics about the task but if you have a finite number of forms in digital form as images, then this seems very possible.

I have personally used [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) with Python a lot and more complex machine learning tasks have become increasingly simple in the past 10 years.

Take for example object detection (e.g. [1](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-recognition-and-object-detection-part1/), [2](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html#face-detection)) to check whether there is anything in a signature field or try extracting the date from an image (e.g [1](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/), [2](https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/extract-text-with-ocr-for-all-image-types-in-python-using-pytesseract-ec3c53e5fc3a)).

I would suggest you start with the simplest thing that would improve your work. A small and easy task will let you build up your knowledge on how to do things.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case and thank you for the guidance; it was exactly what I am looking for. So you definitely think its possible for me to implement something like this given my (lack of) experience?

Comment: Coming from an academic background, I learned most things because I had to solve an experimental problem. All the OpenCV I learned was by myself from online tutorial and stackoverflow. Especially if you already know how to code, it is possible to learn it by yourself. Just be aware that usually things take a lot longer than you think they will (even for a professional developer).